# Identifying film with a couple, pool in back garden, two doors?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I recall seeing a trailer a while ago on IMDb (I believe with a notable actress but I cannot be sure) which featured a couple, with a small swimming pool - blue tiling in their back garden.

There was also some sort of time loop or something of that nature, as I recall them walking in and out of the garden, and there being some confusion over the timeline.

This major plot point seemed to have been left somewhat of a mystery in the trailer understandably, but I am certain something of a supernatural nature of that kind was a plot detail.

I hope this is not too vague to identify this movie. Definitely in English, and 99% sure an American film. It was also certainly made in the last five years, in colour.

The time period within the film itself seems to have been set in modern day, that is, the time period of the making of the film itself.

There were **two doors** on one side of the wall of the house facing the pool I believe. In addition, the trailer I believe exclusively shows the garden with the pool, and this indoor area mostly, and nothing else.

---

**Summary**

- Film set in modern day (time period of making of the film); almost certainly American and made in the last five years. Definitely featured on the front page of IDMb trailers at some point.
- Trailer almost exclusively shows a back garden with a swimming pool with blue tiling, and an area indoors with two doors accessing it. Possibly a kitchen.
- Film certainly features a couple, that is adult male and female.
- A plot detail which seemed somewhat mysterious in the trailer is some confusion arising with these two doors, and the characters entering and exiting. Fairly certain there is some play on timelines, e.g. a time loop.
- In English, made in colour.

Comment: Why the instant downvote? I thought movie identification was on topic...

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What time period was it showing?  Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I personnaly don't downvote questions with not a lot of details, but only when it is not well written. But your question do not contain enough details. Maybe you can check the link in Paulie comments, go through all the point and details them. I think it is year, B&W or color and stuff.

Comment: @M.Polo I've written everything I can remember and my writing is certainly on-point. I'm a 10k user on another SE site...

Comment: Yes, your question is well written, but you can maybe add details, see my edited comment.

Comment: @M.Polo As I've written, the film is set in modern day, and I am almost certain it is a Hollywood film with American speaking actors, made in the past five years. I'll add that it is in colour.

Comment: Is your movie about a girl (child) drowning, and a father going back in time through a door to change that, taking the place of the true father (himself) ?

Comment: @M.Polo No, the film 'features a couple', i.e. there was *definitely* an adult female and male. What is the name of the film to double-check anyway?

Comment: @Paulie_D I never mentioned them travelling anywhere. And no, it's not that awful film about the hot tub time travelling :)

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not like they were travelling back 1000 years where that garden was. As I said in the question, I can't be sure it's a time loop but the film definitely features a device of that kind. I elaborated as I just remembered there were two doors, and I think that has something to do with this device. (To clarify: I don't mean a literal, tangible device.)

Comment: See...now **thats** much better. See how much more you remembered? +1

Comment: @Paulie_D I've added a summary as well. It helps to have someone interrogating you to remember :)

Comment: Does the woman is an artist ?

Comment: @M.Polo That *may* seem familiar, but I can't say either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The One I Love (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_I_Love_(film))

> Confronted with the potential end of their marriage, Ethan (Mark
>   Duplass) and Sophie (Elisabeth Moss) are seeing a therapist (Ted
>   Danson) regularly. After asking them to each play a note on a piano,
>   he identifies a disconnection in their relationship and suggests they
>   take a weekend retreat to a large, secluded estate. The couple decides
>   to try anything to save their marriage and agree to go.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2756032/videoplayer/vi1809820697

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much for finding it and it has a decent rating on IMDb, so I'm definitely going to watch it.